# How does one use font-awesome with mjml?

Tags: html, email, templates, mjml

I am trying to implement an email template that uses font awesome with mjml, I am not sure how to go about this.
I have tried using a cdn as follows:

```
  <mj-head>
    <mj-title>Thank you!</mj-title>
    <mj-style>
      <mj-include path="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

    </mj-style>
    <mj-attributes>
      ...
    </mj-attributes>
  </mj-head>

...
  <mj-text align="center">
        <h3>              
                 Share <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i> 
        </h3>
  </mj-text>
...
```

However this is not functional. Can anyone advise me how best to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to include the font.

```xml
<mjml>
  <mj-head>
    <mj-font name="FontAwesome" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  </mj-head>
</mjml>
```

After this you need to find the unicode number for the font you wish you use. If you pull up the [star icon page](https://fontawesome.com/icons/star) you can see that it is `f005`.

Now you can use the `mj-text` tag to include the font.

```
<mj-text font-family="FontAwesome">&#xf005;</mj-text>
```

This works for solid icons. The difference between icons of class `fas` and `far` is that `fas` has a weight of 900 and `far` a weight of 400. However, in my testing changing the `font-weight` didn't yield any different result. I did discover I could get the `far` version of the star icon by using f006. I checked other icons and the simple act of bumping the unicode number by one did not work. The best way I found to get an icon's unicode equivalent that is not listed on the Font Awesome is to render it in a normal webpage using something like `<i class="far fa-star"></i>"` and then copy-and-paste the icon into http://unicode.scarfboy.com/

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me. However, it didn't work for me when placing the unicode in HTML. It only worked when I place the unicode in CSS like so: `some-element::after {
        content: '\f005';
      }`

Comment: Update for FA5 - use the following in the head: `<mj-head>
    <mj-font  name="Font Awesome 5 Brands" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/brands.min.css" />
    <mj-font name="Font Awesome 5 Free" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/solid.min.css" />
  </mj-head>`, and he `mj-text` should use font-family `Font Awesome 5 Brands` or `Font Awesome 5 Free` (for the solid icons). Other font styles are not free.

Comment: And the unicode value for each glyph can be found in the glyph's page on fa site. E.g. https://fontawesome.com/icons/calendar?style=solid is `f133`

Comment: Does not work in gmail web or gmail android. Displays a square instead of the icon.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers weren't helpful to me.
anyway, instead of including **Font Awesome** as a font,
you can just include it as CSS in `<mj-style>` and use `<i>` tag instead of `<mj-text>`  like that

```
<mjml>
    <mj-head>
        <mj-style>
            @import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css";
        </mj-style>
    </mj-head>
    <mj-body>
        <mj-section>
            <mj-column>
                <mj-text>
                    follow the link
                    <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i>                    
                </mj-text>
            </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
    </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

You can see it in action with this **[DEMO](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/I2XDv3jFBZB)**

Comment: Does not work in gmail web or gmail android. Icon is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<mj-head>
    <mj-font name="FontAwesome" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</mj-head>

<mj-social mode="horizontal" padding="40px 0">
    <mj-social-element name="facebook" padding="0 0px 0" background-color="transparent" icon-size="0px" color="#D72B30" font-size="24px" font-family="FontAwesome" href="#">&#xf09a;</mj-social-element>
    <mj-social-element name="twitter" padding="0 20px 0" background-color="transparent" icon-size="0px" color="#D72B30" font-size="24px" font-family="FontAwesome" href="#">&#xf099;</mj-social-element>
    <mj-social-element name="instagram" padding="0 20px 0" background-color="transparent" icon-size="0px" color="#D72B30" font-size="24px" font-family="FontAwesome" href="#">&#xf16d;</mj-social-element>
</mj-social>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and add a little textual explanation why and how it works and how it differs from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I need simple line icons in mjml - [this answer to the above question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58633589/4852737) was very helpful to me. I might as well share the details for [Simple Line Icons](https://simplelineicons.github.io/).

Include the font in the `mj-head`:

```
<mjml>
  <mj-head>
    <mj-font name="simple-line-icons" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.5.5/css/simple-line-icons.min.css" />
  </mj-head>
</mjml>
```

Then use the `mj-text` tag referencing the font:

```
<mj-text font-family="simple-line-icons">&#xe05c;</mj-text>
```

Or, if I have to use some raw HTML:

```
<mj-raw>
  <div style="font-family:simple-line-icons">&#xe05c;</div>
</mj-raw>
```