# How to use fontawesome 5 with mjml?

Tags: font-awesome, mjml

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I tried to implement this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267909/how-does-one-use-font-awesome-with-mjml/58633589):

```
<mjml>
  
    <mj-head>
      <mj-font name="Font Awesome 5 Free" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/solid.min.css" />
  </mj-head>
  
  <mj-body background-color="#d7dde5">
     
      <mj-section background-color="#ffffff" full-width="full-width">
       <mj-column vertical-align="top">
          <mj-text font-family="Font Awesome 5 Free">&#xf005;</mj-text>
      </mj-column>
      
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://mjml.io/try-it-live/5QvLomsxi73

Maybe your implementation is working?

The above URL is your code. I added the mj-font example from the documentation. I added an mj-text to show the default font.

I conclude the three lines are in three different fonts.

Perhaps you know what to expect your font to look like and this is different?

P.S. This would have been a welcome question at https://mjml.slack.com/  (signup: https://join.slack.com/t/mjml/shared_invite/zt-gqmwfwmr-kPBnfuuB7wof5httaTcXxg). Sorry I was slow to see this here. Someone would have seen it earlier there. Friendly people both places.

They were trying to solve registration problems recently. Please consider registering and hoping for the best!

Comment: Thanks, @BaldEagle!! I didn't know about mjml.slack.com, thanks a lot for this info! About my case, I was interested in fontawesome icons. The whole idea was to display, for instance, this star: https://fontawesome.com/icons/star?style=solid

Comment: I am not able to sign up at https://mjml.slack.com/. I have also tried https://slack.mjml.io/ and failed. Do you know if it is temporarily down or if there is another sign up page?

Comment: mjml.slack.com is the right one. It's working. On one hand, patience is appropriate. On the other hand, they started working on it a while ago, so there might be quite a wait. One person got in by opening an issue on their Github site. Not what it's supposed to be for, but ... maybe that's all there is!

Comment: Did you find a reference to slack.mjml.io somewhere? If MJML has it out there, they should fix it!

Comment: mjml.slack.com is working but it has only a sign in option. It does not have a sign up for new members. The link for slack.mjml.io is in the 'community' tab of mjml.io website. And slack.mjml.io is not working :(

Comment: I have just found the invite link in Github. There is an example inside mjml.slack.com that addresses the icon issue: https://mjml.io/try-it-live/cBliwJ4aF8k . As far as I understood, it is necessary to set the tag mj-style: ```<mj-style>
      .ff  div { font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; } 
    </mj-style>``` and use ```css-class="ff"``` in mj-text, Thanks, @BaldEagle.

Comment: Someone reported the `.io` link to the team on Apr 26. https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/2244. Perhaps the webmaster for that page is really busy; dunno. As to the change they'll make: Perhaps there's no intent to support the `.io` link; maybe it was used in the past.

Comment: There's a new signup link today for https://mjml.slack.com:  https://join.slack.com/t/mjml/shared_invite/zt-gqmwfwmr-kPBnfuuB7wof5httaTcXxg